# How to redirect X output to file?

Tags: linux, video, video-encoding, x11-forwarding, x-server

I know with linux the server X that manage Ui is a protocol with client server.
So the app that use UI didnt directly render thing.
It transmit to server X that render it with hardware.

So the server X can be on a remote machine.
I know that their is some virtual server X.

I have a linux server and want to launch some graphical programme. But i don't want to get the output on my local computer i want it to be stored in a file.(video file)

Is their anyway to directly redirect X to a file?

Comment: Does the remote / forwarding work ok from the server to your local computer? Would running a screen recorder on that work, then automatically log out / quit after? Tried that?

Comment: I want it to be recorded on the server computer. The goal is to make a site that launch programe with parameter and send video link to the site user after so he can download it. So i don't want to record on my computer i want the server to record it even if it dosn't have a display

Comment: That's interesting... might consider having the users just set up a remote / forwarded display and worry about all the rest themselves.

Comment: I could but it's not really user friendly if they have to instal ServerX ssh ecT.... The goal is to simplify for user....
So every one must be able to use it.

Il will try tonight... But a screen recorder on linux like obs can record a virtual screen?

Comment: I'm not sure about screen recorder's details. Might want to edit the question & title a little to focus on the goal more, I think it's having a server run a GUI program (with no input?) and record the GUI to a video file, but without a remote x server?

Comment: yep 
english is not my mother language so it's kinda hard for me to explain what i want exactly ;S

Comment: The X protocol isn't a video format. you need a X server to render it (even if on some virtual screen) and then record that.